# Where is ES6 support in Eclipse Neon?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ecmascript-6, jsdt, eclipse-neon

I downloaded the 'Java EE' and 'web developer' editions of Eclipse Neon to try out the new ES6 support that allegedly exists in this new version of the software.

However both editions appear to contain only the old ES3 validator - with no ES6 in sight.

I could find no mention of ES6/ECMAScript 2015 support in the Eclipse help documents.

I tried searching the Eclipse forums for some clues, but all I found were these two [unanswered](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1735909/?srch=es6#msg_1735909) [posts](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1735198/?srch=es6#msg_1735198) pondering the same question - just where is ES6 support hiding in Eclipse Neon?

Comment: Did you try writing some ES6 code?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question anywhere else? I am having trouble finding any support for Eclipse Neon & JSDT.

Answer (score 2):

#### Free

- [JSDT](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/development/news/3.8M6/jsdt.php)

#### $$$

- [Webclipse / JSJet](https://www.genuitec.com/products/webclipse/download/)

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting with this as well - in the end I [downloaded](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) the latest version of Eclipse and selected "Eclipse IDE for Web and JavaScript Developers"

JSDT Components (As part of WTP) are now [just like any other plugin](https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F).

Very important is also to open JavaScript Files with the **Generic Text Editor** - I have to have a plugin installed, which offers a so called Javasript Editor - but it does not work.